# Best way to use shared code with GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, jar, gwt-rpc

I'm working with a project where I use GWT. There's no problems with it, but now I need my code elsewhere. In fact I need to copy my GWT-RPC methods to another (non-GWT) project.

I think I have 2 options:

1) Create jar which contains shared code and refer to that from GWT (and other) project. Problem is that shared code contains some classes which are needed on GWT client side. As far as I know GWT doesn't support that (client-classes coming from jar).

2) Keep GWT project as it is and use Eclipse's export tool to make jar-file which contains shared classes. Problem is that GWT client classes implements com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable, but that can be solved by making dummy interface with that name.

Any comments?

When I wrote this I got an idea to call directly GWT-RPC somehow from non-GWT project...would it be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT does support client classes coming from jar files. Only requirement is that the jar file should contain the java source files as well. For examples standard gwt classes are in a jar gwt-user.jar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. What do I have to add to projectname.gwt.xml? I tried with  <inherits name="<client class namespace>"/> but got error: "<my client class> can not be found in source packages. Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly."

Comment: Inside your jar place your <Module>.gwt.xml inside a package(for e.g.  com.example.gwt) and then use <inherits name="com.example.gwt.Module"/>

Comment: Just a precision: GWT doesn't care where the java source comes from, it loads everything from classpath, so you can have a JAR with compiled classes (`*.class` files) and another one with source files (`*.java` and `*.gwt.xml` files), and you then put both on the classpath of the GWT compiler or dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

You just create another project and call GWT RPC objects just like that. It will work trust me. I've done that.